# Count necklaces with fixed substring

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

I consider k-ary strings of the form $a_1 \cdots a_n$ where $a_i \in \{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ for $1\le i \le n$. A necklace is the lexicographically smallest representative of an equivalence class where two strings are said to be equivalent if one is a rotation of the other ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics))). The number of all necklaces can be counted using Polya's enumeration theorem.

Now, let $1 \le j \le n$ be fixed. What is the number of necklaces with the additional constraint $a_j = k-1$? Is there a closed form expression for this number?

Comment: When you say $a_j$, do you refer to the lexicographically smallest representative of a necklace?

Comment: Yes exactly. E.g., for $j=1$ there is only one representative while for $j=n$ there are as many as there are prenecklaces of size $n-1$ (The latter follows from, e.g. theorem 2.1 in [Journal of Algorithms 37, 267 (2000)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1632/13ddb0b7b17c4f0e5c59987001a42bb421b3.pdf)).

Comment: Then this question is more about Lyndon words than necklaces.

Comment: Let $L(n,t)$ be the number of Lyndon words of length $n$ with $k-1$ at position $t+1$. You essentially ask for the number $\sum_{d|n} L(d,(j-1)\bmod d)$.